# 20.04 system slows down when video is playing

Tags: nvidia, video, performance

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.8.0-48) on a Lenovo P15s. My settings should match the ones in [Lenovo's guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/tp_p14s_intel_p15s_p15v_ubuntu_20.04_lts_installation_v1.0.pdf). When I'm playing video (particularly when my webcam is on), the system slows down globally - browsers lag, things are slow to respond, etc. For example, using Webex in Chrome causes all my Firefox tabs to stop responding.

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-10610U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation GP108GLM [Quadro P520] / Quadro P520/PCIe/SSE2
```

I suspected the problem was with the Nvidia drivers. I made sure to install the recommended ones - `nvidia-driver-460` in my case (Driver Version: 460.39). That didn't help, nor did falling back to version 450. I also had the same issue with the integrated Intel graphics.

My display is set to 1920x1080 and I'm not using fractional scaling. What other things should I be checking?

Comment: Sounds like throttling. Run this command in a terminal while doing everything else: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 6` and watch for CPU frequency scaling back, perhaps due to temperature and/or power limiting. If you don't have it, I think turbostat is in the linux tools common package, but am not sure.

Comment: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328008/computer-cpu-frequency-not-scaling-high-enough-when-needed-ubuntu-20-04/1328046#1328046) answer, as I think your situation might be very similar.

Comment: Thanks! Both of these comments seem to point to what the issue is. But I've not found a good resource for how to correct it once it's been identified?

Comment: show us what you get from turbostat from before your system is loaded down until it is lagging. We need to see if it is temperature and/or power throttling. Delete the --quiet part just so you can see your power limits. If you are power throttling without being to hot then maybe some improvement can be made.