# What makes my CPU frequency drop on intensive application?

Tags: cpu, frequency, overclocking, turbo-boost

I am currently developing a software related to robotics, using Ros and the OpenVino toolkit on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am doing some intensive computation related to computer vision, so I am looking for the best performances.

To do so, I changed my cpu-freq governor to 'performance', through the cpupower tool:

> sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance

As a result, when nothing is running, my CPU is close to its maximum ( I have a i7-10510U, whit tubo freq = 4.9GHz):

```
driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.90 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.90 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 4.45 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

But as soon as I run my Ros program, it drops to approximately 2.3GHz:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.90 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.90 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.32 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Then I checked the temperature, as I thought it could be the limiting factor, but it has some room:

```
Package id 0:  +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +78.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

So what is limiting the cpu frequency in my case? (The RAM has also lots of room, 5Gb/16Gb, and my average CPU load is 70%)
I tried to get over it, by changing my drivers from intel_pstate to acpi-cpufreq, but then my maximum CPU freq available droped, and when I tried to set the cpu freq by hand while being in usermode, it did not change anything ( The frequency was still the same).

I believe there is a (security?) reason why it is stuck to this frequency, so what is it? And what would be the solution to get over it?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I ran Prime95 test, and this is what I get through turbostat:

```
turbostat version 19.08.31 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x16 CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:c (6:142:12)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR - EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
cpu6: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): SGX
cpu6: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00040005 (Locked SGX)
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 192 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
TSC: 2304 MHz (24000000 Hz * 192 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 2300 max_mhz: 4900 bus_mhz: 100
cpu6: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00401cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 17476 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 15 Watts
cpu6: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x4043df1011700
4 * 100.0 = 400.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
23 * 100.0 = 2300.0 MHz base frequency
cpu6: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0024005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu6: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x2b2b3031
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
49 * 100.0 = 4900.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x00000012 (base_ratio=18)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00080050 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL1=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL1=0 LVL1_RATIO=8 PKG_TDP_LVL1=80)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x001700c8 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL2=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL2=0 LVL2_RATIO=23 PKG_TDP_LVL2=200)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x00000000 ( lock=0)
cpu6: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000011 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=17 lock=0)
cpu6: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x1e008008 (UNdemote-C3, UNdemote-C1, demote-C3, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=8 (unlimited))
cpu6: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu6: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu6: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x01081231 (high 49 guar 18 eff 8 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x80003104 (min 4 max 49 des 0 epp 0x80 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000000 (Dis_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000000 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: 0x00000006 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000078 (15 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x4200e800dc80c8 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (25.000000 Watts, 28.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: DISabled (29.000000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x5400de00140000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 1.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x0a640000 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x883e0802 (38 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x0000884e (valid, 79872 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00008876 (valid, 120832 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00008894 (valid, 151552 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x000088fa (valid, 256000 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x0000894c (valid, 339968 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00008bf2 (valid, 1034240 ns)

1.06    855 4313    37  1.30    0.00    0.31
1.14    960 6394    36  1.30    0.00    0.31
78.24   2693    30532   79  19.92   0.04    0.35
99.62   2130    33525   74  16.44   0.01    0.30
99.74   2026    33059   77  14.93   0.01    0.31
99.75   2032    33879   80  14.95   0.01    0.30
99.76   2024    31722   81  14.95   0.00    0.29
99.74   2016    35433   82  14.95   0.02    0.32
99.68   2008    56927   83  14.95   0.14    0.51
99.72   2026    38053   81  14.96   0.04    0.36
99.72   2034    38046   78  14.96   0.05    0.37
99.73   2041    49197   77  14.95   0.02    0.33
99.71   2036    39762   77  14.95   0.05    0.38
99.72   2034    28531   77  14.95   0.04    0.36
```

So the power seems to be limited to 15W

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is no Ubuntu 18. there is an 18.04 might that be it?

Comment: Sorry, it is 18.04!

Comment: There have been several similar questions in the last few days. Please see [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328008/computer-cpu-frequency-not-scaling-high-enough-when-needed-ubuntu-20-04), including the comments, edit your question with the same requested information, then flag me with a comment and I will have a look. It is likely your power budget.

Comment: Oh, by the way, 79 degrees processor package temperature is as high as I would ever allow, regardless of the absolute limit. Actually, I set my limit to 74 degrees.

Comment: Hi Doug, and thanks for your reply. I edited my post accorded to the information from the other topic. In turbostat, is it this line which is supposed to tell me the power limit?
`RAPL: 17476 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 15 Watts`

I havn't found yet the command line to allow me to change this limit, would you have an hint?

A more general question, how misleading is the turoboost frequency specification, when trying to find the appropriate CPU? Because then I am far from the 4.9GHz.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't flag me via @DiXcipuli (except me) in a comment, I don't know to come here and look. Your TDP is 15 watts, but has been increased to 25 via power limit 1. I do not know why the override is not working. Have a look all around `/sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl` . Also look at the various "enable" flags. But notice your temperature at 15 watts is already high enough, so I wouldn't increase the max power anyhow.